# React Passing component state between tabs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, stringify

I'm trying to pass the state of the App between 2 tabs, I'm not using Redux, just pure React.

My approach is to check if localStorage is empty, if not then I get the item and right after it I remove the item. When I click on my open window button I save the state before the new window is opened. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, my state has an array in it and it doesn't seem to be serialized/deserialized properly. 
Here's the code

My App class:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { nombre: 'Escritorio', vtnAbiertas: [] };     
    this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //alert('Ventana renderizada')
    //window.localStorage.removeItem('AppState')
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {   
        const estadoAlmacenado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('AppState'))
        this.setState({
          nombre: 'editor',
          vtnAbiertas: [
            ...estadoAlmacenado.vtnAbiertas
          ]
        })    
        localStorage.removeItem('AppState') 
      }
    else
      alert('LocalStorage no tiene valores almacenados')
  }

  handleStateChange = (param) => {
    this.setState({
      vtnAbiertas: [
        ...this.state.vtnAbiertas,
        param
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {   
    const themes = ['#2c2f33', 'teal']
    const backgroundColor = themes[0]       

    return (
      this.state.nombre === 'Escritorio' ?
      // /////////////// RENDERIZA EL ESCRITORIO
      <div className='App'>
        <Header backgroundColor = {backgroundColor} />

        <Landing 
          state = {this.state}
          ventanas = {this.state.vtnAbiertas}
          handleStateChange = {this.handleStateChange} 
          backgroundColor = {backgroundColor}                    
        />

        <Footer backgroundColor = {backgroundColor}/>
      </div>
      :
      // /////////////// RENDERIZA UN EDITOR
      <div className='App'>
        <Header backgroundColor = {backgroundColor} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the code for the handler which opens the window and stores the state:

```
handleAbrirVentana = () => {     
        let nuevaVentana = window.open(window.self, '')
        this.props.handleStateChange(nuevaVentana)
        localStorage.setItem('AppState', JSON.stringify(this.props.state))        
    }
```

I tried a lot of different things, but I can't get an array serialized properly.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code thoroughly, and I'm not sure if local storage should work, but you may need to ensure that the setItem call runs before the new window is opened.

Comment: Actually, you cannot serialize a Window object, and even if you could, I don't think it would do what you want it to do. What are you *trying* to do?